# Mysql Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, lumen

I am using Lumen with mysql version version **5.6.31.** 
I have a view in the Database joining 3 tables. When I am trying to query the view I am getting this error.

[image]

When I tried PDO prepare statement for tables its working but for the views its not working.

Can't figure out reason. can anyone help. Any help appreciated.

There is nothing unusual in the code. same laravel stuff..
here is the code i used to query the view.

```
$query = \DB::table('active_user_view')
        ->select('*')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($username){
            if(!empty($username)){
                return $query->where('username', '=', $username)
                       ->orWhere('email', '=', $username);         
            }
        });        
        $query->where('password','=',md5($password));

        return $query->first();
```

The wired thing is .  when I restart the mysql it works for a while in server(centos) and then after a while error starts again... it works locally in linux server..

Comment: show all the source code related to this or else this will just close or get downvoted.

Comment: I added the code.. Is there any way i can solve it... can u please help..

Comment: Come to the [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/campaigns) chat room if you want and ping me with an @ sign. You would probably have to bundle up some tables and scripts and stuff for me to recreate it. With dummy data. I am not a Laravel programmer but could do PDO. Also, what you are doing with passwords would appear to be not a good practice.